# Why I can't find my own question?

Tags: support, search

This search

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=is%3aq%20answers%3a0%20created%3a2017-06-01..%20tags%3a%5brails%5d

Does not find this (my own) question

[`form_for` is bypassing model accessors. How to make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509420/form-for-is-bypassing-model-accessors-how-to-make-it-stop)

Only 7 questions are found.

`is:q answers:0 created:2017-06-01.. tags:[rails]`

Also, if you use

`is:q answers:0 created:2017-06-01.. tags:[ruby-on-rails]`

then it only finds 1 question.

Comment: Remove "tags:" and it looks fine.

Comment: I want to search by tags. It's the top option in 'advanced search tips'.

Comment: The `tags:` string is not part of the syntax. It's just the section label. The *square brackets* denote a tag, so `[foo]` matches results with the `foo` tag.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/advanced-search-parameters-jobs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misreading that section.  The column contains *subject*: *syntax* entries.  So the line;

```
tags    [tag]
```

tells you that to search by tag you need to use the `[tag]` syntax. You are using `tags:[tag]` instead, and I'm surprised you got any hits at all with that syntax.

The correct  search is

```
is:q answers:0 created:2017-06-01.. [rails]
```

which yields [392 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+answers%3A0+created%3A2017-06-01..+%5Brails%5D), your post included.

Comment: He may confused with markdown `[tag:rails]` and `[rails]`

Comment: @SagarV: from the comments on the question: *I want to search by tags. It's the top option in 'advanced search tips'.*